# Editext validation android

Tags: android

In Edittext Android :
How to implement this feature if user entered any valid numeric value it should get displayed in the form of decimal value.
e.g If user enters 4 then it should get displayed as 4.000 instead of only 4.
Also can be done using DONE button click handler of virtual keypad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

      //Check your et value and set it back.
      // Retrieve 4.. set it to 4.000

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on your XML?

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Comment: yes i am using that input type but it do allow numeric types i want strictly decimal input type.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string you are getting from editext to double or float in the click of a done button or wherever you want.